# Filter by 2 fields in VBA Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm using VBA for Access. I have some forms that I want filter.

With the follow code:

```
a = "ID =" & idwanted
Form_Form1.Form.Filter = a
Form_Form1.Form.FilterOn = True
```

It works nice, the form is correctly filtred. But I need to filter by 2 fields, something like that:

```
a = "ID =" & idwanted
b = "Name =" & namewanted
Form_Form1.Form.Filter = a And b
Form_Form1.Form.FilterOn = True
```

But it give me a error (non match types), but all the fields and variables (a & b) are integer.

(If I do only with b, it filter it correctly.)

Thanks for read me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just make sure you use the right data type literal. Also you need to concatenate the two conditions. Finally `Name` is a reserved word, so you need to enclose them in []. Something like,

```
a = "ID =" & idwanted
b = "[Name] = '" & namewanted & "'"
Form_Form1.Form.Filter = a & " And " & b
Form_Form1.Form.FilterOn = True
```